# Restify only accept get method, even from same domain

Tags: node.js, restify

I have encountered a problem in restify. I can only use get-methods in the API. Normally it seems like people have had problems when it comes to CORS, but I can't even use it with the same domain. I have tried a lot and for a little while it work with the same domain at localhost.

But then I modified my code a little and it didn't work. Also I could not seem to get the parameters in the req.body or req.params for my POST request. I'm not using any preflight request either.

```
'use strict';
var restify = require('restify'),
plugins = require('restify-plugins'),
config = require('./config.js'),
personController = require('./routes/person-controller')


var server = restify.createServer({
name: config.name,
version: config.version,
})


server.use(plugins.jsonBodyParser({ mapParams: true }))
server.use(plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable))
server.use(plugins.queryParser({ mapParams: true }))
server.pre(restify.CORS({
origins: [
    '*'
],
headers: [
    "authorization",
    "withcredentials",
    "x-requested-with",
    "x-forwarded-for",
    "x-real-ip",
    "x-customheader",
    "user-agent",
    "keep-alive",
    "host",
    "accept",
    "connection",
    "upgrade",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "if-modified-since",
    "cache-control",
    "Accept-Encoding",
    "Accept-Language",
    "User-Agent",
    "Accept",
    "DNT",
    "Connection",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
    "Cache-Control",
    "Pragma",
    "Content-Length",
    "Content-Type",
    "Accept-Type"
],
 methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT"]
})
)
server.use(plugins.fullResponse())

server.get("/api/values", personController.readAll);
server.get("/api/values/:id", personController.readOne);
server.post("/api/values/", personController.createPerson);
server.put("/api/values/", personController.updatePerson);
server.del("/api/values/", personController.delPerson);



server.on('uncaughtException', (req, res, route, err) => {
log.error(err.stack)
res.send(err)
});

server.listen(config.port, function () {

})
```

I'd like to solve it this way, but if I can't I may have to switch back to Express.

NEW Info:
Right now I can use full crude when I use my firefox browser. I use a server to host my node application. The server is a vmware with ubuntu server distro using nginx. However when I post the exact same request with jmeter I cannot access the full crud functionality, only get. Here is the request that works from fire fox

```
Host: 192.168.131.128
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101
Firefox/52.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 174
Pragma: no-cache
```

It seems like the different sources of the requests somehow triggers different CORS settings on the server.

Comment: can you post the post request ? do you set `application/json` to the content type of request? body parser is not in `.use` of restify ..

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your fast reply. I just changed server.use(plugins.fullResponse()) to server.pre(plugins.fullResponse()) and it works now for the same origin atleast but not for postman. I know i have used content-type application before but now when i added it I se the parameters in the request!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below class.

import CORS from './path/to/CORS.js';

new CORS(server).enableCorsRoutes();

```
class CORS {

    constructor(server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    enableCorsRoutes = () => {
        this.setCorsCredentialHeaders();
        this.getCorsRoutes().forEach((route) => {
            this.server.opts(route, this.enableCors);
        });
    }

    enableCors = (req, res) => {
        const header = req.header('origin');
        if (!this.isOriginAllowed(header)) {
            return res.send(405);
        }
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', header);
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', this.getAllowedHeaders().join(','));
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', this.getAllowedMethods().join(','));
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', this.getCacheTimeForPreflightRequest());
        return res.send(200);
    }

    isOriginAllowed = (origin) => {
        let result = false;
        this.getAllowedOrigins().forEach((allowedOrigin) => {
            if (origin.includes(allowedOrigin)) {
                result = true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    getAllowedHeaders = () => ([
        'cache-control',
        'content-type',
        'x-signature',
        'x-test-mode',
        'x-request-id',
    ])

    getAllowedMethods = () => ([
        'OPTIONS',
        'GET',
        'POST',
        'PUT',
        'DELETE',
        'PATCH',
    ])

    getAllowedOrigins = () => ([
        'example.com',
        'example.org'
    ])

    getCorsRoutes = () => ([
        '/\.*/',
    ])

    getCacheTimeForPreflightRequest = () => {
        return 864000; // ten days in seconds
    }

    setCorsCredentialHeaders = () => {
        this.server.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.once('header', () => {
                let isCorsRoute = false;
                this.getCorsRoutes().forEach((route) => {
                    if (new RegExp(route).test(req.url)) {
                        isCorsRoute = true;
                    }
                });
                if (isCorsRoute && req.header('origin')) {
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin'));
                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                }
            });
            next();
        });
    }
}

export default CORS;
```